# Different syntax for accessing columns in 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have written the following code to access the second column of array `lst1`

```
import numpy
lst1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
lst1 = numpy.array(lst1)
lst2 = lst1[:,1]
lst3 = lst1[0::,1]

print lst2
print lst3
```

The output is:

```
[2 5 8]
[2 5 8]
```

Is there a difference between `lst2` & `lst3`? Is the difference in syntax between `lst2` & `lst3` significant?

How to achieve the same result using lists (not using `numpy.array`)?

Comment: Why do you want to do it with lists?  If you're doing something that is difficult to do with lists and easy to do with numpy arrays, you should probably just use numpy arrays.

Comment: Okay. I understand. I am just trying to understand if there is an easier way to do the same using lists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionally

```
lst2 = lst1[:,1]
lst3 = lst1[0::,1]
```

are the same. The single `:` translates to `slice(None,None,None)`, the other to `slice(0,None,None)`.  In both cases the `numpy` indexing function (`.__getitem__`), takes that to mean, start at 0, end at the end, and step by 1.

Lists take slices by don't take tuples, e.g. `(slice(0,None,None), 1)`.  They don't have any kind of multidimensional syntax.

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

is a nested list.  That is, it's a list that contains lists.  The outer list knows nothing about the nature of the inner lists.  The list comprehension that the other answer gives is the most logical way of accessing elements within the inner lists.

It may be worth noting that you can apply that list comprehension to the array.  That is, you can iterate over the rows, and select items from each row.  You usually don't need to do that, but it's worth knowing.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a list comprehension pretty easily:

```
>>> lst1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> [a[1] for a in lst1]
[2, 5, 8]
```

When it comes to nested lists, there is no way to get columns as a list without copying, and a list comprehension is the simplest way to copy that data out. You could also write some wrapper around the list that would provide a view into it that looked like a column without copying, but at that point you might as well stick with numpy.